# ag-grid: use sortComparator in applyColumnState

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

i use ag-grid version 28 in Angular. I have this table (it has some more columns but these are the two relevant for my question):

```
this.columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: "`Deliverydate",
    field: "deliverydate",
    width: 120,
    valueFormatter: function (params) {
      if (moment(params.value).isValid()) {
        return moment(params.value).format("DD.MM.YYYY");
      }
      return "";
    },
    sortable: true,
    filter: false,
    editable: false,
    cellStyle: { fontSize: "10px" },
  },
  {
    headerName: "State",
    field: "state",
    sortable: true,
    filter: false,
    editable: false,
    width: 150,
    cellStyle: { fontSize: "10px" },
  },
];
```

Also i want to use the applyColumnState() function to set some default sorting rules. First it should be sorted by "state". The values pending, arranged, delivered should be prioritized. Also state can have some other unknown values. Second the deliverdate should be used as sort criteria.
I implemented it as follows:

```
this.gridColumnApi.applyColumnState({
  state: [
    {
      colId: "state",
      sortIndex: 0,
      sort: 'asc',
      sortComparator: function (a, b) {
        const priority = ["Pending", "Arranged", "Delivered"];
        const priorityA = priority.indexOf(a);
        const priorityB = priority.indexOf(b);
        console.debug("priority: ", a, b);
        console.debug("priorityA: ", priorityA);
        console.debug("priorityB: ", priorityB);

        // Handle unknown values
        if (priorityA === -1 && priorityB === -1) {
          // Both values are unknown, maintain their original order
          return 0;
        } else if (priorityA === -1) {
          // Only value A is unknown, place it after value B
          return 1;
        } else if (priorityB === -1) {
          // Only value B is unknown, place it after value A
          return -1;
        }

        // Both values are known, compare based on priority
        return priorityA - priorityB;
      },
    },
    {
      colId: "deliverydate",
      sort: "asc",
      sortIndex: 1,
    },
  ],
  defaultState: { sort: null },
});
```

I cant figure out why this appears to not be working, as the state rule does not work as expected. The sorting still has "arranged" at the top. Is it even possible to use the sortComparator in the applyColumnState function?